# Avoid duplicate "if conditions" in django template HTML tables

Tags: html, django, django-templates, html-table

Depending on the user accessing a web page, the generated HTML tables may show extra columns. My current implementation checks a flag on every row within my template file, where `show_secret_column` is a flag set by the *view*:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-md-4">Column 1 Header</th>
                <th class="col-md-2">Column 2 Header</th>
                <th class="col-md-2">Column 3 Header</th>
                {% if show_secret_column %}
                <th class="col-md-2">Secret Column Header</th> 
                {% endif %}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for row in row %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ row.a }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.b }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.c }}</td>
                {% if show_secret_column %}
                <td>{{ row.secret }}</td>
                {% endif %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Is this a bad approach? Is there any other way recommended to perform this check only once in the template and generate the extra column?

Comment: this looks fine to me

Comment: @thedarklord47, can I check if the repeated `if` conditions are executing very slowly, leading to poor scaling as the rows increase? It "feels" like it's slowing down, and I'd rather not address this two weeks later when the stress testers complain...

Comment: how many rows is this table expected to hold?

Comment: @thedarklord47 the largest table in the existing version of our website was 40k rows

Comment: page length + fetch time is going to be a much larger impact on performance than these if statements. have you thought about pagination? I can't imagine any scenario where a 40k row table would be a good user experience.

Comment: I think you're trying to solve a non-existent problem. Unless you are having performance issues with this particular code (unlikely - a simple boolean check is not expensive), just leave it as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really want to micro-optimize for a row count that large (which I highly suggest you don't) you could duplicate the template like this:

```
{% if show_secret_column %}
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-4">Column 1 Header</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Column 2 Header</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Column 3 Header</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Secret Column Header</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for row in row %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.a }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.b }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.c }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.secret }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
{% else %}
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-4">Column 1 Header</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Column 2 Header</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Column 3 Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for row in row %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.a }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.b }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.c }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
{% endif %}
```

I just want to re-iterate that if I saw this in my code I would be horrified. It is super brittle now (you would have to be careful to duplicate all changes made to both sections). It is also just a lot of bloat and an eyesore.

Your main objective should be to not have a table with 40k rows in the first place. That said, this will do what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, the table will be paginated and loaded 100 rows at a time. This (loop hoisting) was the obvious solution, but it has even more duplicate code than mine, and unfortunately AFAIK, Python isn't going to do this automatically.

Comment: I could put everything but the secret column in a separate template to avoid the duplication, and then just `{% include %}` it in both places to avoid the "copy changes" problem. I was just hoping that the templating would have a nicer way out... Oh well...

Comment: if you are only rendering 100 rows, your rendering time will be negligible. I still would not worry about the extra ifs. I think you are micro-optimizing.

Comment: It's a 100 rows for one user. At peak load, we have ~400 active users per minute. Point taken though.